# Extension suggestions

Tags: magento2

I apologize, if this is not the correct place to ask, but is there a place where I can describe my problem and people can suggest extensions (free or paid), that would help me. As I'm pretty sure it's illegal to advertise on stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento has a forum for exactly that.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension

Comment: didn't even know about this, thanks!

Comment: This is great, wasn't aware of this, thanks! Will accept your answer as soon as I can